# border radius is not reflecting in one element

Tags: html, css, border-radius

i am trying to some challenges in frontendmentor.io.trying to replicate a product card.I have almost done.But i am stuck with border radius to the .right element, i applied border top right and bottom right radius as 10 px  to .right element.but it is not reflecting in the browser.and another problem is the width of the card.there is slight diffrents between the width of the actual project and mine.actual project width is lesser than mine.i have attached both images here.kindly fix these two problem

original
[image]

[![

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

main{width: 100%;}

.card {
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    

}
.right{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    row-gap: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.right .itemcategory{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.left{
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url("/images/image-product-desktop.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.des{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.offerprice {
    color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
    font-size: 28px;
}
.beforeprice{
    font-size: 14px;
    
}

button{
    background-color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;

    

}

button img{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Product preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p class="itemcategory">Perfume</p>
        <h1>Gabrielle<br> Essence Eau <br>De Parfum</h1>
        <p class="des"> A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
      
      <div class="price">
          <p class="offerprice">$149.99</p>
          <p class="beforeprice">$169.99</p>
      </div>
         <button>
        <img src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="" >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
      
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZIbu.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZIbu.jpg)

Comment: overflow:hidden where you apply border-radius

Comment: Just apply a basic `border-radius: 10px` to the `.card`element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem can easily be fixed by adding a "border-radius" to the .card class. The second problem can be fixed by changing the height of the .card class and adding "padding-top" to the .right class. I haven't changed the hight in my example (code below) since I don't have access to the image.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

main{width: 100%;}

.card {
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
.right{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    row-gap: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.right .itemcategory{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.left{
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url("/images/image-product-desktop.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.des{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Product preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p class="itemcategory">Perfume</p>
        <h1>Gabrielle<br> Essence Eau <br>De Parfum</h1>
        <p class="des"> A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
      
      <div class="price">
          <p class="offerprice">$149.99</p>
          <p class="beforeprice">$169.99</p>
      </div>
         <button>
        <img src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="" >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
      
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `div` tag for the `.right` element that should come after the `button` element.

Then just add `border-radius: 10px` on the `.card` element, which means you can remove the border-radius styles on `.left` and `.right` elements.

If border-radius is still not applied, add `overflow: hidden` to the `.card` element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

main{width: 100%;}

.card {
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.right{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    row-gap: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.right .itemcategory{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.left{
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url("/images/image-product-desktop.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.des{
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.offerprice {
    color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
    font-size: 28px;
}
.beforeprice{
    font-size: 14px;
}

button{
    background-color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
}

button img{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Product preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p class="itemcategory">Perfume</p>
        <h1>Gabrielle<br> Essence Eau <br>De Parfum</h1>
        <p class="des"> A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
      
      <div class="price">
          <p class="offerprice">$149.99</p>
          <p class="beforeprice">$169.99</p>
      </div>
         <button>
        <img src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="" >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
      
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to give border-radius to only .card class because it's parent div contains the left and right block. so if we give border to parent div then we should not give border to children div.
I think your problem is solve now. 